# How to looping data tuple in list Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

How to use loops to get this output

```
AGR Anggora  
PRS Persia  
MNC Main Coon
```

from this data structure:

```
a = [('AGR', 'Anggora'), ('PRS', 'Persia'), ('MNC', 'Main Coon')]
```

I have tried like this but it fails:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   for z in range(len(a)):
       print(a[i][z], a[z][i])
```

Comment: `for abbreviation, name in a: print(f'{abbreviation} {name}')`

Comment: @MaartenFabré You are assuming OP is using Python 3.6

Comment: it shouldn't be that hard to find out for the OP to see how to print this if he isn't

Comment: @MaartenFabré And yet it would be better to provide a generic answer that works on all versions of Python.

Comment: thank you sir for answer, i will try later. maybe answer from @StellarDoor5319 is better for newbie like me hehehehe

Comment: @MaartenFabré You don't even need the string format to be honest: `for abbreviation, name in a: print(abbreviation, name)` will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unpack (using `*`) each tuple from your list in `print`:

```
a = [('AGR', 'Anggora'), ('PRS', 'Persia'), ('MNC', 'Main Coon')]
for tup in a:
    print(*tup)
```

Result:

```
AGR Anggora
PRS Persia
MNC Main Coon
```

Comment: I am not sure, but probably not the greatest option for someone (apparently) just starting to use Python: too magic

Comment: @SergeyAntopolskiy My answer demonstrates a less "magic" solution - printing each value separately.

Comment: It's hard to know what is too "magic". That always depends on what topics are already known. But for this problem unpacking is definitely the shortest and best suited solution, isn't it?

Comment: thank you sir for answer, but i don't understand. your code is work but i really really don't understand -_-

Comment: @Oncom You might want to have a look at ["Unpacking argument lists"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). There the Python documentation covers the unpacking operator :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
for b in a:
    print(b[0], b[1])
```

Comment: It's better to avoid variable names that shadow built-in functions (for example `tuple`).

Comment: @MSeifert I usually do, this just illustrates the code better. I'll change it.

Comment: hi sir thanks for answer, what if a is a lot ?
so i have to put b[number] ?

Comment: @Oncom If you mean that there are, say, 200 tuples within `a`, then you can simply leave the code as it is. If you mean that there are 200 items in each tuple, replace the contents of the print function's brackets with `*b`.

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 hmmm, i see i see. i understand now sir. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function:

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.
>   A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in
>   iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is
>   the string providing this method.

Your code will look like this:

```
a = [('AGR', 'Anggora'), ('PRS', 'Persia'), ('MNC', 'Main Coon')]

for t in a:
    print(" ".join(t))
```

and the output will be:

```
AGR Anggora
PRS Persia
MNC Main Coon
```

Comment: hi sir, i already found answer for my problem. but very thank you for helping me :) later, i will read about `join` :)

Comment: you don't need to iterate with the index

Comment: @MaartenFabré Thanks for the tip. I adapted the solution to the code posted but It's better without the index.

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution.
it's kinda weird, but it works ._.

here my code.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i][0], a[i][1])
```

i think my answer is almost same like @StellarDoor5319 answer.

Thank for you guys who help me for this problem :)